# Mysql data source is not working, when application deployed on wildfly

Tags: java, mysql, deployment, nullpointerexception, wildfly

The web application is working fine while working with Eclipse IDE

But after deploying it on the wildfly server is not bale to access the database. The below jsf page has datatable below **ADD New Data** and on submit **ADD New Data** button a dialog will be appeared for adding data, but it is not showing after deploying on wildfly. And getting null pointer exception for the pages which are accessing the database.

```
    Context Path:/STCMedicalSystem
Servlet Path:/secure/MedVoucUpdate.jsf
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stc.medical.dao.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:47)
    at com.stc.medical.service.RegMedicalVoucherService.getAllMedicalNos(RegMedicalVoucherService.java:21)
    at com.stc.medical.upload.RegMedicalVoucherAction.<init>(RegMedicalVoucherAction.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:387)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:247)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:92)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:126)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:175)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:347)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.calculatePage(DataTable.java:769)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:160)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:595)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:90)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:566)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:152)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:566)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    ... 42 more
```

[image: getting blank page with only button]

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>STCMedicalSystem</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/stc_medical</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>start</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

page.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>STC Medical system</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
        href="../resources/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="../resources/css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="../resources/css/sdmenu.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/sdmenu.js"></script>
<h:body>
<h:form id="dbform">
                                                            <p:growl id="growl" />
                                                            <h:panelGrid>
                                                                <p:outputPanel>
                                                                    <h:outputText value="Filter by Flag(E, R, S, D, N): " />
                                                                    <h:selectOneMenu immediate="true"
                                                                        value="#{allMedVocAction.selectedFlag}"
                                                                        onchange="submit()"
                                                                        valueChangeListener="#{allMedVocAction.flagFilter}"
                                                                        render="true">
                                                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="all" />
                                                                        <f:selectItems id="options"
                                                                            value="#{allMedVocAction.flagNames}" />
                                                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                                            <h:panelGroup id="dbpanelgrid">
                                                                <p:dataTable style="width:800px;" id="tbl" var="med"
                                                                    value="#{allMedVocAction.searchResults}"
                                                                    paginator="true"
                                                                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                                                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowKey="med.file"
                                                                    selection="med.selectedMedNo"
                                                                    columnClasses="text,number,number,number,text,text"
                                                                    rowClasses="table-evenRow,table-oddRow"
                                                                    update="excelPdfPanelGroup" rows="5"
                                                                    selectionMode="single"
                                                                    rowSelectListener="#{allMedVocAction.onDataSelect}">
    <p:column sortBy="#{med.brno}" filterBy="#{med.brno}"
                                                                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                                                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                                                            <h:outputText value="BRNO" />
                                                                        </f:facet>
                                                                        <h:outputText value="#{med.brno}" />
                                                                    </p:column>
<p:column style="text-align:center;">
                                                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                                                            <h:outputText value="EDIT" />
                                                                        </f:facet>
                                                                        <p:commandButton title="EDIT" onclick="dlg2.show();"
                                                                            render="tbl"
                                                                            action="#{allMedVocAction.editMcodeDetails}"
                                                                            image="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"
                                                                            update="editfrom:editdevice,display" immediate="true">
                                                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{med}"
                                                                                target="#{allMedVocAction.selectedMedNo}" />
                                                                        </p:commandButton>
                                                                    </p:column>
                                                                </p:dataTable>
                                                                <!-- Delete Dialog box -->
                                                                <!-- Preview Dialog box -->
                                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                                        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Getting response code 500 in tomcat access log for jsf pages after deployment in tomcat server.
context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context path="/stc_medical">
<Resource name="jdbc/stc_medical" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="root" 
              password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stc_medical?autoReconnect=true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

ConnectionPool class:

```
    public class ConnectionPool {
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPool() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic
                    .lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/stc_medical");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get an instance of the connection pool
     * 
     * @return ConnectionPool
     */
    public static ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    /**
     * Get a connection
     * 
     * @return Connection
     */
    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Free a connection
     * 
     * @param c
     */
    public void freeConnection(Connection c) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin in tomcat lib directory while deploying war file, but not able to access the database.
I tried many ways, but not able to find the solution.

Comment: and WHAT does the error log show? And you seem to be using a very old PF version

Comment: OH and what is 'the other server'?

Comment: I am using tomcat server, i have already deployed the application where it is working fine, when i tried to deploy on other system it is not working.

Comment: Getting response 500 in tomcat access log for jsf pages and it is not accessing the database

Comment: the log files present in tomcat folder, not showing any exception only 500 response for the jsf pages.

Comment: I am not able to access the database getting null pointer exception after deploying the war file in tomcat server

Comment: Tomcat connects to mysqld on localhost. Are tomcat and database deployed and running on the same server? Are there any firewall or mysql grants restrictions?

Comment: tomcat and database are deployed on the same machine.

Comment: I have already deployed the same application on another system it is working fine, when i tried to deploy it on other system not working

Comment: @YuriLachin There is no error while running with eclipse IDE.

Comment: @YuriLachin Please help me for the above issue

Comment: @Kukeltje Please help on the above issue

Comment: I don't use Tomcat but wildfly, so I can't help

Comment: @Kukeltje Can you tell me the procedure for installing wildfly, and deploying war file in wildfly

Comment: Search engines are your friend

Comment: @Kukeltje getting nullpointer exception at connection pool class at line 47  for the pages which are accessing the database in wildfly

Comment: I don't use resources this way in wildfly, I use the normal java-ee  datasources. With injection etc. And I was never suggesting you should switch to Wildfly. Help ends here for me. I was initially only informed about this question due to you wrongly tagging it with JSF